# reading Jframe attribute and writing its value to an xml file

Tags: java, swing

I writing a java program that will read the content of JFrame and based on the value of that an xml file will be created which will contain the attributes and its corresponding value.
I have two classes one having java swing and another creating an xml file.
On my frame i have few check boxes and few combo boxes and I want to create the xml containing attribute and value of these.
I am not able to set the value of these attributes at all in my CreateXML.java file.
If anybody has some solution please help me out.

Regards,
SHK

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 1):

AlexR is basically right.

However, a far simpler solution to the larger problem is to look into the usage of [XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html), which should handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` is an indirect subclass of `Container` that implements method `public Component[] getComponents()`. Once you have reference to you JFrame you can iterate over its components and create XML if you need. Pay attention that if one of the components is instance of Container you should go inside recursively.

I believe that this is what you should implement into your CreateXML class.